# Calculate Interval mean of column in matlab (interval not fixed)

Tags: matlab, mean, intervals

I have an array (2000x2) with two variables and want to calculate the mean of column 2 at intervals determined by column 1. How can i do this?

```
speed=(:,1); %values range from 0-100 cm/s
press=(:,2);
```

I want to calculate mean pressure at at 5 cm/s intervals of speed. So that I get 20 values for pressure that correspond to 20 intervals of speed.

Should be simple, but I'm still a beginner in Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

The [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) function does just that:

```
data = [0 20 33 44 22 56 25 47 81 90; 3 5 4 3 2 4 5 5 6 0].';
speed = data(:,1);
press = data(:,2);
sz = 5; % interval size
fill = NaN; % fill value in the result, for empty groups
group = floor(speed/sz)+1; % compute index of group for each value
result = accumarray(group, press, [], @mean, NaN); % compute mean of each group
```

Comment: That looks like it can work. Does a interval size of 5 means the speed intervals go from 0 to 5.0, 5.01 to 10 etc?

Comment: @lisse As it is now, they go from `0` to `4.999...`; then from `5` to `9.999...` etc. You can adapt that to your needs changing the line `group = floor(speed/sz)+1`

Comment: Thanks for the help!